# Instagram denying API requests

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, instagram-api

I'm having a strange issue. I currently have API approval from Instagram for the following:

basic
public_content
comments

I'm using Laravel and Vinkla's Instagram package which is a wrapper for [Elogram](https://github.com/larabros/elogram).

Having had my application approved by Instagram, it went into live mode. Now for every request I get the following message:

```
OAuthPermissionsException in AbstractAdapter.php line 69:
This client has not been approved to access this resource.
```

This indicates that Instagram are blocking the request on the grounds that I don't have the necessary scopes. This all worked fine in Sandbox and my credentials haven't changed.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted the issue myself. It was an access token issue.

Comment: I can't find Vinkla's Elogram Instagram package. Only a very simple solution to get the user data. But there is no Elogram involved. Can you help me out with the right repo?

Comment: Sure - the repo is [https://github.com/vinkla/instagram]. It's basically a wrapper of the Elogram package https://github.com/larabros/elogram

Comment: Is it? I just found a very simple user/media request! There is no option for other endpoints?

Comment: Hey @fabian Yeah it's not well documented in that regarded but it alludes to this in a closed issue on the repo. Essentially, any method you can do on Elogram, you can do here. Check it out: https://github.com/vinkla/instagram/issues/33

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the user to the Sandbox users in the Instagram Developer site. Then the user has to accept the invite in his/her Instagram account.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: The application is live but I've sorted the issue - it was an access_token problem. Thanks anyway!